# XSD generate a MAP<String, Boolean> properties

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, xsd

I am trying to generate java class from XSD file, which contains `Map<String, Boolean`. I've read tutorial (http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/jaxb-xsd-to-java-maphashmap-example.html) which says that I have to use Adapter and Binding in order to achieve desired result.

But for some reason after generation property is a `List` instead of the `Map`. Could you please help me to figure out my mistake?

Thanks!

My XSD schema:

```
<xs:element name="AutoCompleteReq">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="queryString" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="boostingFactors" type="test:StringBooleanMapModeller" minOccurs="0"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="StringBooleanMapModeller">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="value" type="xs:boolean"/>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

My Binding file:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="AutoCompleteReq.xsd">

  <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='AutoCompleteReq']//xs:element[@name='boostingFactors']">
   <jaxb:property>
    <jaxb:baseType name="com.company.support.jaxb.StringBooleanMap&lt;String,Boolean&gt;" />
   </jaxb:property>
  </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

StringBooleanMap.java

```
package com.company.support.jaxb;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringBooleanMapAdapter.class)
public class StringBooleanMap<String, Boolean> extends HashMap<String, Boolean> {

}
```

StringBooleanMapAdapter.java

```
package com.company.support.jaxb;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

import com.company.xml.representation.StringBooleanMapModeller;

public class StringBooleanMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<StringBooleanMapModeller, HashMap<String, Boolean>> {

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Boolean> unmarshal(StringBooleanMapModeller v)
            throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        for(StringBooleanMapModeller.Entry e : v.getEntry())
        {
            map.put(e.getKey(), e.isValue());
        }

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public StringBooleanMapModeller marshal(HashMap<String, Boolean> v)
            throws Exception {

        StringBooleanMapModeller modeller = new StringBooleanMapModeller();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : v.entrySet())
        {
            StringBooleanMapModeller.Entry e = new StringBooleanMapModeller.Entry();
            e.setKey(entry.getKey());
            e.setValue(entry.getValue());
            modeller.getEntry().add(e);
        }
        return modeller;
    }
}
```

pom.xml (piece for XSD generation)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Representations</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>XSD/Representation</schemaDirectory>
                            <packageName>com.company.xml.representation</packageName>
                            <bindingDirectory>XSD/Representation</bindingDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb/.representation</staleFile>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Events</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>XSD/Representation/Event</schemaDirectory>
                            <packageName>com.company.xml.representation.event</packageName>
                            <bindingDirectory>XSD/Representation/Event</bindingDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb/.event</staleFile>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: It might help if you post the error message you're getting. It shouldn't be possible for your code to compile if you're asking for a Map from a method that will return a List.

Comment: It could be a million things. Make sure the binding file ends with .xjb. Try to run the jaxb generator manually and see if you get better error messages. Test the xpath expression with some other tool.

Comment: My initial guess would be incorrect binding directory. Perhaps you should use the 'bindingFiles' instead. Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<String, Boolean>` from behind StringBooleanMap, it doesn't do what you think it's doing. String and Boolean are interpreted as generic parameters, not as java.lang.String and java.lang.Boolean.

Correct:

```
package com.company.support.jaxb;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringBooleanMapAdapter.class)
public class StringBooleanMap extends HashMap<String, Boolean> {

}
```

Your code was interpreted as:

```
public class StringBooleanMap<S,B> extends HashMap<S,B> {
```

Also, change the jaxb:baseType reference to:

```
<jaxb:baseType name="com.company.support.jaxb.StringBooleanMap" />
```